# Performance loss in sql left join when using int

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I have a question about left join performance.

Supose I have this 2 tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE "Jobs" (
        "Id" INT NOT NULL,
        "Department" VARCHAR(25) NULL,
        "Job" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ("Id", "JobName")
    );

    CREATE TABLE "Workers" (
        "Id" INT NOT NULL,
            "JobID" INT NOT NULL,
        "WorkerName" VARCHAR(25) NULL,
            "WorkerSurname" VARCHAR(25) NULL,
        "JobName" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
    );
```

Now, I want to left join both tables in order to get all the jobs on an specific department for an specific worker, even if the worker does´t take that job.

```
select t1.job, t1.department, t2.WorkerName, t2.WorkerSurname 
from (SELECT distinct job, department FROM Jobs WHERE  DEpartment= @depto) t1 
left join dbo.Workers t2 on t1.id=t2.Jobid and t2.WorkerName=@NAME
```

This sql tooks about 0,171ms.

But, if I join with "Job" instead of "id":

```
select t1.job, t1.department, t2.WorkerName, t2.WorkerSurname 
from (SELECT distinct job, department FROM Jobs WHERE  DEpartment= @depto) t1 
left join dbo.Workers t2 on t1.Job=t2.JobName and t2.WorkerName=@NAME
```

I tooks about 0,030 ms.

Can anyone explain me why is this happening? i thought integer joins were faster than varchar ones

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the query plans?

Comment: Can you explain the primary key definition for the Jobs table? What's the "JobName" column doing there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not contain sufficient information. The first query isn't even valid. As `t1` contains no `id` column.